# nullPointer Exception, where do I go wrong?

Tags: java

I'm working my way into the Head First Java book, and now trying to build a Chatroom. I have a ChatServer and a ChatClient and the can connect to each other. But when I try to send a message I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at VerySimpleChatServer.tellEveryone(VerySimpleChatServer.java:61)
    at VerySimpleChatServer$ClientHandler.run(VerySimpleChatServer.java:29)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I checked my tellEveryone but I can not see where I'm going wrong. I don't see any where I have any pointers that point to nothing.

Can anyone help me along a little?

Code for ClientServer:

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.net.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class VerySimpleChatServer { 

ArrayList clientOutputStreams; 

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable { 
    BufferedReader reader; 
    Socket sock; 

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket) { 
        try { 
            sock = clientSocket; 
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader); 
        } catch(Exception ex)   
        { 
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 

    public void run() { 
        String message; 
        try { 
            while (( message = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                System.out.println(" read " + message); 
                tellEveryone(message);
            } 
            } 
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 

public static void main (String[] args) { 
    new VerySimpleChatServer(). go(); 
} 

public void go() { 
    List<PrintWriter>clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<>(); 
    try { 
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket( 5000); 
        while( true) { 
            Socket clientSocket = serverSock.accept(); 
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter( clientSocket.getOutputStream()); 
            clientOutputStreams.add( writer); 
            Thread t = new Thread( new ClientHandler( clientSocket)); 
            t.start(); System.out.println(" got a connection");
        } 
        } catch(Exception ex) 
        { 
            ex.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator(); 
    while(it.hasNext()) { 
        try { 
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next(); 
            writer.println(message); 
            writer.flush();
            } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Code for the ChatClient:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleChatClient {
JTextArea incoming;
JTextField outgoing;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket sock;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleChatClient client = new SimpleChatClient();
    client.go();
}

public void go()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ludicrously Simple Chat Client");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();        
    incoming = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);

    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    outgoing = new JTextField(20);      
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());

    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);

    setUpNetworking();

    Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    readerThread.start();

    frame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(400, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


private void setUpNetworking()
{
    try
    {
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new      InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("networking established");
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {
        try
        {
            writer.println(outgoing.getText());
            writer.flush();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        outgoing.setText("");
        outgoing.requestFocus();
    }
}


public class IncomingReader implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        String message;
        try
        {
            while ( (message = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }//close while
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

edit:

Line 60 to 74 of SimpleChatServerClient:

```
    public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator(); 
    while(it.hasNext()) { 
        try { 
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next(); 
            writer.println(message); 
            writer.flush();
            } 
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: What is line 61 of "VerySimpleChatServer"?

Comment: You are calling a method on ClientOutputStream, which isn't initialized. In your 'go' method, you initialize a local variable with a similar name, but that won't help you there.

Comment: Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();  - you never initilialize the clientOutputStreams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `clientOutputStreams` that you are using in `go`

```
List<PrintWriter>clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
```

is local to that method

The `clientOutputStreams` used in

```
public void tellEveryone(String message) {
    Iterator it = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
```

is the class variable which has never been initialized

Comment: Not really a 'global' variable, since Java doesn't have those, but an instance variable.

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for your comment.  I was weighing up whether to use the proper term and maybe confuse the OP

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation. I got it but Stultuske made me realise it was not the right term.

Comment: offtopic: what can I do in the future to avoid my negative score? I searched before posted, used code quotes, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the reply's. I changed the following to get the code working:

Changed in line 7

```
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;
```

into

```
ArrayList<PrintWriter> clientOutputStreams;
```

And in my `public void go`

Changed

```
List<PrintWriter>clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<>();
```

into

```
clientOutputStreams = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();
```

Thanks for the help!